# Was there an al aqsa mosque in arabia / place referred to as masjid al aqsa , in arabia, during mohammeds time that mohammed went to?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, masjid

I have heard that during the days of Mohammed’s existence, there was a village adjacent to Mecca that was called al-Jarana.  Near(or in?) this village were two mosques.  The mosque which was the closest was named al-Masjid al-Adna and the mosque which was the farthest was named al-Masjid al-Aqsa. (adna/nearest) and aqsa(further). Mohammed prayed in these two mosques, al-Masjid al-Adna and al-Masjid al-Aqsa.  I have heard that these two mosques were in Medina in Mohammed's time.  Is that correct?

Comment: Where have you heard this? Any references?

Comment: @TheZ i'm not sure as just a friend mentioned it,